# In Django, how do I choose data from one table and count from a corresponding table and output the same?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models as described below:

```
class Post(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
  details = models.TextField()

class Comment(models.Model):
  blog_post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
  comment = models.TextField()
```

I want to write a view that shows all entries from Post and the corresponding number of comments for each post.

I know I can get the comments count by doing:    `Comment.objects.filter(blog_post__title__icontains='xxx').count()`

I just want to output a HTML page where all posts show up and each post should have a corresponding comment count (just the count, not the actual comment entries/data). How do I do this? How do I pass the list of posts and the corresponding comment count for each post to the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [aggregation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/aggregation/). When you're getting your list of posts, you tell Django you want to count the related Comments at the same time:

```
from django.db.models import Count
posts = Post.objects.all().annotate(comment_count=Count('comment'))
```

Now each post in the `posts` queryset has a `comment_count` attribute, which is the number of related comments.